# Log responseEntity with specific fields

Tags: java, spring

I have an API where the response type is `ResponseEntity<Book>` and I would want to log the final json response string but with certain fields (e.g. "`name`" field only) only rather than all fields in Book, what's the best way to do this ?

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

 @JsonProperty("id")
 private String id;

 @JsonProperty("name")
 private String name;

 @JsonProperty("isbn")
 private String isbn;

 //rest of implementation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested a demo covers two cases, like that:

Case 1, in which `Book` has getter methods.
If you want to response `name` only, it will work by ignore `id` and `isbn` using `@JsonIgnore`.

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

  @JsonIgnore
  private String id;

  private String name;

  @JsonIgnore
  private String isbn;

  //rest of implementation


  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
  }
}
```

Case 2, in which `Book` doesn't has any getter method.
If you want to response `name` only, it will work by using `@JsonProperty` on `name` only.

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

  private String id;

  @JsonProperty
  private String name;

  private String isbn;

  //rest of implementation

}
```